# Java ProcessBuilder Shutdown System Error

Tags: java, processbuilder

```
 ProcessBuilder pb;
 Process process;
 String command ="shutdown -s";
    try {
        pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", command) 
        process = pb.start();
        process.waitFor();
        if (process.exitValue() == 0) {                  
            //success
        } else {
            //handle error
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle error
    }
```

When I try to get inputstream and run that block of code system goes into an infinite loop.
Then I changed the code as seen above. However when I run it it gets exit value of 1 and can not shutdown system.

Any ideas?

**PS:** I don't want to use java run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

command should be:

```
String command ="shutdown.exe -s";
```

instead of:

```
String command ="shutdown -s";
```

Comment: i just did some testing directly in cmd ... it seems to split arguments inside double quotes. i.e `cmd> cmd /C  "foo.exe arg1 arg2"` is interpreted as `cmd> cmd /C  "foo.exe" "arg1" "arg2"` and `cmd> cmd /C  "foo.exe "arg1 arg2""` is equivalent to `cmd> cmd /C  foo.exe "arg1 arg2"` witch is a strange behaviour since if one have wanted to have `arg1 agr2` interpreted as a single argument containing space character he would intuitively write `cmd> cmd /C  "foo.exe \"arg1 arg2\""`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "shutown", "-s");
```

the argument(s) command for the constructor ProcessBuilder(String... command) are passed each as 1 argument to the executable, this allows to have spaces in the argument.

the way you are executing the command is equivalent to

`cmd /C "shutdown -s"`

thus "shutdown -s" is interpreted as a single argument.

Comment: my other commands works even I don't pass their arguments separately?